# Java y Linux - Cómo cambiar la variable de entorno JAVA_HOME para todos los usuarios en Linux

Tags: java, linux

Tengo como sistema operativo Linux Mint en su versión que se basa en Debian 10. En mi usuario tengo instalado varias versiones de Java, más concretamente la 1.6, que la utilizo con el software Frascati; la versión 1.8 para proyectos en general ya que me conviene que tiene integrado el JavaFx; y por último la versión 16 que la utilizo con Spring, ya que me exigen esa versión en la universidad. Entonces, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo hago para cambiar la variable de entorno JAVA_HOME cada vez que quiero cambiar de versión de java?

He leído que para eso lo más correcto sería crear un archivo .sh en la ruta `/etc/profile.d/` y luego de crearla ejecutar el comando `chmod +x file.sh`. Pero lo hago, le doy los permisos, cierro y luego abro sesión y no me aparece nada cuando ejecuto el comando `echo $JAVA_HOME`. Esto es lo que tengo en dicho archivo (el cual llamé `java_home.sh`, no se si el nombre importe):

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:/bin/java::")
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Según lo que dice en este enlace [how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users), esa es la mejor forma de tenerlo, ya que me permite tener la versión de java que elegí con el comando `update-alternatives --config java` posterior al cierre e inicio de sesión. Pero como dije anteriormente no me funciona.

La otra opción que observe es la de escribir eso que tengo en el archivo .sh en la ruta `/etc/profile`, al final del documento. Pero el problema de ello es que tengo que usar la consola si o si para poder que se me cambie la variable `JAVA_HOME` al iniciar sesión y eso es lo que quiero evitar.

Comment: Y por qué es lo que quieres evitar?

Comment: Te recomiendo usar SDKMan en lugar de alternatives, es mucho más amigable y sencillo de usar

Comment: @PabloLozano Interesante lo de SDKMan, no tenía idea de que existira. Pero investigando un poco, me entra el interrogante de que si podré cambiar a la versión de java 6 mediante SDKMan, ya que dicho comando no lo soporta dentro de los JDK que deja descargar.

Comment: Puedes bajarte el zip de java 6 (no lo instales) y añadirlo a sdkman fácilmente. Por cierto, java 6 es de 2007,creo. Es hora de pasar a otra versión :P

Comment: @PabloLozano Listo gracias, tendré en cuenta lo que me dices de SDKMan. Con respecto a la versión de java 6, el software que uso (frascati), sólo funciona con dicha versión entonces me toca tenerlo si o si en la pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es tener varios scripts (digamos, en `/usr/local/bin`) que puedas llamar y que te configuren las variables que necesites, por ejemplo. El truco de hacerlo de esta forma es que el script que vayas a llamar lo tienes que hacer con `.`. Por ejemplo:

```
. /usr/local/bin/setup_spring.sh
. /usr/local/bin/setup_frascati.sh
```

Fijate que no es `./usr/bla`. Es `. /usr/bla`. Al tenerlos en `/usr/local/bin`, los podría usar cualquiera. Si los colocas dentro de tu `~` con los permisos adecuados, solo tú podrías usarlos.

La otra forma *sencilla* es tener varios alias en tu bash que hagan ese trabajo.

Comment: Gracias, esta también es una buena opción aparte de la que me dieron con la de SDKMan. La probé en otro computador que tengo con el mismo sistema operativo y funcionó. Por cierto, lo de los alias es bastante interesante, lo estaré investigando para aplicarlo en otras cosas que tengo.